# How to reassign value of element of char array in C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I would like to change the value of the third letter in apple to "a".
Using the indirection this way gives me a compiler error saying:
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char c[6]="apple";
*c[2]="a";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c[2]='a';` or `c[2]=*"a";`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: While technically valid, I think most programmers consider `*"a"` to be ugly syntax.

Comment: @abelenky I agree completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
c[2]='a';
```

In C and C++ `"x"` is a type of `const char [2]`. To specify a character you need to use `'x'` that is a type of `const char`.

Answer (score 3):

Double-quotes create null-terminated strings.

Instead, you want a single-quoted character, which is just a single `char` value:

```
c[2]='a';  // Now your string is "apale"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead try

```
 *(c+2)='a'
```

You should learn more about how pointers work in c.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

c[2]='a'

OR

*(c+2)='a'

Any one of them will work..